# Custom subView disappearing in iOS7 when going back

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview

I am adding a custom view programmatically to another view defined in the Storyboard, but when I go back to this view, the custom one disappears.

This is happening only when coming back from Storyboard segues, when I push a View programmatically and go back, it doesn't disappear.

Also, it's happening only on iOS 7. iOS 6 is fine.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

```
collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(collectionView.frame.origin.x, collectionView.frame.origin.y, collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height - ADROTATORHEIGHT);

CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat x = self.view.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - ADROTATORHEIGHT;

adHolder.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, ADROTATORHEIGHT);
adHolder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[adHolder addSubview:adViewController.view];
[self.view addSubview:adHolder];

[collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: @David This code is in the first view controller (viewDidLoad) that is loaded from the Storyboard, when the app is launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, I solved it by repositioning the frame every time the view will appear (in viewWillApear with the view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)).